# Необходимость в запятой в "Жизнь как она есть"

Tags: пунктуация

Жизнь как она есть возникает в ходе выполнения действий.

Запятая не требуется?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что *она* - подлежащее, а *есть* - сказуемое в придаточном предложении. Простые предложения, имеющие свою грамматическую основу, отделяются запятыми с двух сторон.

В названии фильма запятая присутствует:
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Жизнь,_как_она_есть](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8C,_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)